# Custom pandas Datetime offset / frequency for trading times: 9:30AM-4:00PM business days except US holidays

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series, algorithmic-trading, datetimeindex

Trading data is recorded on non-holiday business days starting at 9:30AM, and data is recorded periodically (5 seconds, 5 minutes, 30 minutes, etc) until 4:00PM.  For instance, [9:30AM, 9:35AM,...,3:50PM, 3:55PM] on non-holiday business days are times for which there are 5 minute data.

Does `pandas` have the capabilities required to correctly work with this sort of time structure? I have seen that there are ways of adding [custom holidays](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#custom-business-days) to business days (9:00AM-4:00PM). But I have yet to see anyway of defining custom business hours, like (9:30AM-4:00PM). For instance, is it possible to define a custom *trading hour* [9:30AM, 10:30AM, ... 3:30PM], or *trading 5 minutes* that takes advantage of whatever code powers the *business hour*?

For instance, is there a `pandas`-powered  way to generate a `DatetimeIndex` of, lets say, 5 minute frequency that follows the rules of trading times:

- Mon: 9:30AM, 9:35AM, ... 3:50PM, 3:55PM
- Tue: 9:30AM, 9:35AM, ... 3:50PM, 3:55PM
- ...
- Fri: 9:30AM, 9:35AM, ... 3:50PM, 3:55PM
- Mon: Federal holiday, no times
- Tue: 9:30AM, 9:35AM, ... 3:50PM, 3:55PM
- (and so forth)

Or is this just not supported at this time?

In other words, what methods/classes does `pandas` currently have to implement this kind of functionality? If there are none, does anyone know of other libraries that could help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same question, at least the part about

> is there a pandas-powered way to generate a DatetimeIndex of, lets say, 5 minute frequency that follows the rules of trading times?

And I have an answer for you below, but first, regarding:

> Does pandas have the capabilities required to correctly work with this sort of time structure?

The phrase "work with" is rather vague; What "work" is it that you want to do?
Pandas can definitely work correctly with this sort of time structure ***to do some things*** but perhaps not others.

and regarding.

> For instance, is it possible to define a custom trading hour [9:30AM, 10:30AM, ... 3:30PM] ... ?

The answer is yes, however there are some limitations which I will describe below.
That said, **I will focus primarily on the ability to generate a datetime index that follows the rules of trading times and trading days**, and demonstrate below how to do this using pandas.  First I will mention some of the existing pandas tools and their limitations.

I spent the better part of yesterday evening researching this.  Most all of the functions that pandas has to generate a datetime index range accept an input frequency **`freq`** as a string (such as `'15T'` for 15 minutes, or `'D'` for daily).

These same functions will also typically accept a [**pandas time series offset**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/offset_frequency.html) object in place of the frequency.  There are many different kinds of offsets:  Each defines a frequency that can have rules, such as skipping over weekends (for example, [offsets.BusinessDay](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessDay.html)) or generating a datetime index for [business hours only](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessHour.html) such as only from 9am till 5pm.

**The main problem that I have encountered with frequencies, and with offset objects, is that** (for the most part) **there is no way to combine them.**

For example, using the [**BusinessHour offset class**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessHour.html) I can specify that I want to generate an index containing only business hours (trading hours), and I can even do so only for business days (over a bunch of dates) *but I cannot combine this with specifying a frequency* such as once per minute, or once every 15 minutes.  Rather, the [**BusinessHour**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.BusinessHour.html) offset class appears to default to a frequence of **once per hour only**, and there is no way I have found to change it.

Alternatively, for example, I can use the `pandas.bdate_range()` specifying a frequency of `'30T'` to generate an index point every 30 minutes, but non-business days will be included.  If I set the frequency to `'B'` for business days only, then it skips non-business days, but I only get one index point per day.  No way, that I found, to combine these two frequencies.

The simplest solution that I came up with is to generate a list of business days (trading days) and then loop through that list generating an index for each date at the desired frequency (1 minute, or 5 minutes, or 15 minutes) from open time till close time on each date.  I then use pandas `DatetimeIndex.union_many()` method to combine the datetime indexes into one.   The code looks like this:

```py
def trading_day_range(bday_start=None,bday_end=None,bday_freq='B',
                      open_time='09:30',close_time='16:00',iday_freq='15T',weekmask=None):

    if bday_start is None: bday_start = pd.Timestamp.today()
    if bday_end   is None: bday_end = bday_start + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

    daily = []
    for d in pd.bdate_range(start=bday_start,end=bday_end,freq=bday_freq,weekmask=weekmask):
        topen  = pd.Timestamp(open_time)
        d1    = d.replace(hour=topen.hour,minute=topen.minute)
        tclose = pd.Timestamp(close_time)
        d2    = d.replace(hour=tclose.hour,minute=tclose.minute+1)
        daily.append(pd.date_range(d1,d2,freq=iday_freq))
   
    index = daily[0].union_many(daily[1:])
    return index
```

Here are some examples of using it:

```py
ix = trading_day_range()
print('len(ix)=',len(ix))
print(ix[20:40])
print(ix[-20:])
```

```
len(ix)= 54
DatetimeIndex(['2021-04-13 14:30:00', '2021-04-13 14:45:00',
               '2021-04-13 15:00:00', '2021-04-13 15:15:00',
               '2021-04-13 15:30:00', '2021-04-13 15:45:00',
               '2021-04-13 16:00:00', '2021-04-14 09:30:00',
               '2021-04-14 09:45:00', '2021-04-14 10:00:00',
               '2021-04-14 10:15:00', '2021-04-14 10:30:00',
               '2021-04-14 10:45:00', '2021-04-14 11:00:00',
               '2021-04-14 11:15:00', '2021-04-14 11:30:00',
               '2021-04-14 11:45:00', '2021-04-14 12:00:00',
               '2021-04-14 12:15:00', '2021-04-14 12:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
DatetimeIndex(['2021-04-14 11:15:00', '2021-04-14 11:30:00',
               '2021-04-14 11:45:00', '2021-04-14 12:00:00',
               '2021-04-14 12:15:00', '2021-04-14 12:30:00',
               '2021-04-14 12:45:00', '2021-04-14 13:00:00',
               '2021-04-14 13:15:00', '2021-04-14 13:30:00',
               '2021-04-14 13:45:00', '2021-04-14 14:00:00',
               '2021-04-14 14:15:00', '2021-04-14 14:30:00',
               '2021-04-14 14:45:00', '2021-04-14 15:00:00',
               '2021-04-14 15:15:00', '2021-04-14 15:30:00',
               '2021-04-14 15:45:00', '2021-04-14 16:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

```py
ix1 = trading_day_range('01/01/2021 09:30','01/13/2021 16:00',
                         bday_freq='C',iday_freq='30T',weekmask='Wed Thu Fri')
print('len(ix1)=',len(ix1))
print(ix1[20:40])
print(ix1[-20:])
```

```
len(ix1)= 70
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-06 12:30:00', '2021-01-06 13:00:00',
               '2021-01-06 13:30:00', '2021-01-06 14:00:00',
               '2021-01-06 14:30:00', '2021-01-06 15:00:00',
               '2021-01-06 15:30:00', '2021-01-06 16:00:00',
               '2021-01-07 09:30:00', '2021-01-07 10:00:00',
               '2021-01-07 10:30:00', '2021-01-07 11:00:00',
               '2021-01-07 11:30:00', '2021-01-07 12:00:00',
               '2021-01-07 12:30:00', '2021-01-07 13:00:00',
               '2021-01-07 13:30:00', '2021-01-07 14:00:00',
               '2021-01-07 14:30:00', '2021-01-07 15:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
DatetimeIndex(['2021-01-08 13:30:00', '2021-01-08 14:00:00',
               '2021-01-08 14:30:00', '2021-01-08 15:00:00',
               '2021-01-08 15:30:00', '2021-01-08 16:00:00',
               '2021-01-13 09:30:00', '2021-01-13 10:00:00',
               '2021-01-13 10:30:00', '2021-01-13 11:00:00',
               '2021-01-13 11:30:00', '2021-01-13 12:00:00',
               '2021-01-13 12:30:00', '2021-01-13 13:00:00',
               '2021-01-13 13:30:00', '2021-01-13 14:00:00',
               '2021-01-13 14:30:00', '2021-01-13 15:00:00',
               '2021-01-13 15:30:00', '2021-01-13 16:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: Came across this post, I agree, this is a really important feature for anyone dealing with financial data. You may, for instance, want a stock trading at 9:30 AM to be able to look back 10 business minutes to 4:20 PM the prior day for a window calculation.

Is there a way to convert this date time index to an offset for use with pd.rolling()?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are asking.  There is ***no*** `pd.rolling()`; rather there is **`pd.Series.rolling()`** and **`pd.DataFrame.rolling()`**.  It ***is*** *possible* to use these rolling functions with a Series or DataFrame that contains one of these generated DatetimeIndex objects as the index of the Series or DataFrame, and it will behave accordingly.  Perhaps give it a try, and see if it works to your liking.

Comment: I said it generically as I thought it was obvious what I am referring to. Apparently not. To be clear - I am referring to passing in a custom offset, rather than an integer, to said functions.

Comment: It does appear [accotding to the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) that the `window` parameter of rolling *can* accept an Offset object (instead of just an integer number of rows).  I have no idea how it would then behave, but a few simple experiments should reveal the answer.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can generate a 5min code in a normal way and then use DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time to get datetimeindex for custom trading times (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html )

example:
if i is the datetime index created by you then below code will give you the custom datetimeindex for trading times

i [i.indexer_between_time('09:30:00', '04:00:00', include_end=False) ]